# Limit points on the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ and the set $A=[1,5) \cup (7,11]$

Tags: general-topology

By definition, let A be a subset of a topological space X. A point x in X is a limit point of A if every neighborhood of x intersects A in a point other than x. Therefore, the sets whose elements are all limit points of A in $\mathbb{R}$ would be [1,11], [1,5], [7,11], and {1,5,7,11}.

Am I missing any?

Comment: Well, the point 6 which belongs to interval $[1,11]$ is not a limit point of set $A$.

Comment: I'll tell you the answer and you should then be able to figure out why: $[1, 5] \cup [7, 11]$

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is strange, as you are basically listing **four** sets, and three of them are subsets of the first.

So, it is now not really clear what you think the limit points are. For example, is $6$ a limit point or not? I don't know what you think, because $6$ is an element of $[1,11]$, but it isn't an element of the remaining three sets...

---

Furthermore, if you think all points in $[1,11]$ are limit points, then you are wrong because $6$ is **not** a limit point of $A$ ($(5.5, 6.5)$ does not intersect $A$)

Comment: I just made a correction to reflect that I was referring to sets whose elements are all limit points...

Comment: @Learner It's no better. You need **one** set. So, is $6$ a limit point (since it is in $[1,11]$ or not (since it **isn't** in $[1,5]$)?

Comment: OK- {1,5,7,11} and (1,5)

Comment: @Learner That's still two sets.

Comment: Why can't there be be more than one set whose elements are all limit points of A in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Learner Because it's bad form. I still don't know if $1$ is a limit point (it is in the first set) or not (it isn't in the second). Do you mean to say that the *union* of these two sets is your answer? If so, please edit your original question accordingly.

Comment: @Learner There can be, and of course there is, more than one set whose elements are limit points. But the question says "what are the limit points", and the standard answer for this is to state the **set of all limit points**. Or, use any other way that makes it clear what all the limit points are.